# Delete item on the second click on mobile devices (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a UL with a hover effect on its LIs. When hovering there is a red div appears on the left and when you click on the LI it toggles a class to the text inside of it. It's all ok on the desktop version but when I switch to the mobile version the first tap should activate only the hover effect. Instead of that it acticates the hover and toggle a class immediately. I want to have on mobile version the first tap activates hover and then if it's still active next taps toggle the class. Pls try the code on mobile version it's all clear there what I mean. 
Thanks

```js
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('completed');
});

$('ul').on('click', 'div', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(250, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    //prevent event bubbling
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

li{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

li div{
  background-color:red;
  width:0;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  display:inline-block;
}

li:hover div{
  width: 40px;
}

.completed {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Groceries</h1>
  <ul>
  <li><div></div><p>carrot</p></li>
  <li><div></div><p>onion</p></li>
  <li><div></div><p>tomato</p></li>
  </ul>
```

**Update:** I'm almost got it, got the first toggle on the second tap, the problem is the next toggle occurs on the double tap too:

```
var isMobile = false;
var isClicked = 0;

$('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {

   if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
       Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          isMobile = true;
          isClicked++;
   }

   if(!isMobile || isClicked > 1){
          $(this).toggleClass('completed');
          isClicked = 0;
   }
});
```

Comment: you want to show red div on tap not on hover right?

Comment: On the mobile version only the first tap activates hover effect. You can't call the hover effect on the mobile with another way. I want it with the first tap and toggle the class with next taps on the element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all disable hover with CSS using @media queries for mobile devices.

Second create a jquery method for tap/click on that

at which you want to show red div. you can do something like this

```
$('li').on('click' , function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 760){ // Enter maximum width of mobile device here for which you want to perform this action
      // show red div here
    }
    return false;
});
```

Also keep in mind @media and $(window).width() should have same pixels/size

EDIT:

try replacing this

```
var isMobile = false;
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
   Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      isMobile = true;
}
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {



   if(isMobile){
      $(this).toggleClass('completed');
   }
});
```

And let the other code in the click function and try again

Comment: Sorry Kaleem, didn't get it :/ I'm almost got it, the logic is: when I tap the LI element for the first time it causes hovering effect with no toggling (I realized that with isClicked property), so after that click the LI element is "active" now and when it's active and the user didn't click on the another LI I want to toggle class with a single click.

Comment: actually javascript code does not wait for other code to complete. in your case before assigning isMobile to true, your second condition is running in which you are toggling class. so that it is toggling second time. please see update again.

Comment: It looks like I can't explain clearly. It doesn't toggling second time, it toggling with the double tap instead of doing it with a single as the LI element is "active" now from the very first tap.

Comment: Okay i understand your point. have you tried with latest update?

Comment: $( "li" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );
 
  function tapHandler( event ){
    $( event.target ).toggleClass('completed');
  }

Answer (score 0):

You should use [touchstart](http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/) event to handle touch event on mobile but don't forget to check if ontouchstart is available.

```js
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('hover')) {
      $(this).toggleClass('completed');
    }
  } else {
      $(this).toggleClass('completed');
  }
});

$('ul').on('touchstart', 'li', function(e) {
  var link = $(this); //preselect the link
  if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    link.addClass("hover");
    $('li').not(this).removeClass("hover");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; //extra, and to make sure the function has consistent return points
  }
});

$('ul').on('click', 'div', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(250, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  //prevent event bubbling
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

li div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  display: inline-block;
}

li:hover div,
li.hover div{
  width: 40px;
}

.completed {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Groceries</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div></div>
      <p>carrot</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div></div>
      <p>onion</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div></div>
      <p>tomato</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: pls see the update. Your solution is little bit difficult for me and I need to change much code in my project. Could you pls give some fix to my code. Thanks